# Batch extracting multiple .aac tracks from an .mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, mp4, aac

How do I create a ffmpeg .bat file that will let me drop in .mp4 file(s) and extract multiple .aac tracks without any converting or transcoding taking place ? I do know that there will always be 3 .aac tracks.

I have tried using:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -c copy -map 0:a:0 Output.aac
```

But that extracts only the first audio stream.

Ideally i would like to be able:

-videoname.mp4

-drop videoname.mp4 onto bat

-outputs videonameaudio1.aac, videonameaudio2.aac, videonameaudio3.aac

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

The command will be

```
ffmpeg -i videoname.mp4 -c copy -map 0:a:0 videonameaudio1.aac -c copy -map 0:a:1 videonameaudio2.aac -c copy -map 0:a:2 videonameaudio3.aac
```